# Create MySQLdb database using Python script

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm having troubles with creating a database and tables. The database needs to be created within a Python script.

```
#connect method has 4 parameters:
#localhost (where mysql db is located), 
#database user name, 
#account password, 
#database name    
db1 = MS.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****",db="test")
```

returns

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'test'")
```

So clearly, the db1 needs to be created first, but how? I've tried CREATE before the connect() statement but get errors.

Once the database is created, how do I create tables? 
Thanks,
Tom

Here is the syntax, this works, at least the first time around. The second time naturally returns that the db already exists. Now to figure out how to use the drop command properly.

```
   db = MS.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
   db1 = db.cursor()
   db1.execute('CREATE DATABASE test1')
```

So this works great the first time through. The second time through provides a warning "db already exists". How to deal with this? The following is how I think it should work, but doesn't. OR should it be an if statement, looking for if it already exists, do not populate?

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "test1")
```

Comment: Not to be rude but have you tried googling it? Drop the db="test" from the connect and go read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html or http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: Yes, lots of googling (and RTFM is not rude, but I wouldn't be asking if I could have found it). And yes no error when I drop the "test". The question is how do you create the db using python, not SQL.

Comment: Here is the syntax, this works, at least the first time around. The second time naturally returns that the db already exists. Now to figure out how to use the drop command properly.
   db = MS.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
   db1 = db.cursor()
   db1.execute('CREATE DATABASE test1')

Comment: "DROP DATABASE test1". While it is a good thing to learn SQL you might also want to look into Object Relational Mappers, with the arguably best one being http://www.sqlalchemy.org/.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) to create the database:

```
db1 = MS.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
cursor = db1.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE mydata'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Use [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) to create the table:

```
sql = '''CREATE TABLE foo (
       bar VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
       ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
       '''
cursor.execute(sql)
```

There are a lot of options when creating a table. If you are not sure what the right SQL should be, it may help to use a graphical tool like [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to create a table, and then use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to discover what SQL is needed to create it:

```
mysql> show create table foo \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: foo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `bar` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

phpmyadmin can also show you what SQL it used to perform all sorts of operations. This can be a convenient way to learn some basic SQL.

Once you've experimented with this, then you can write the SQL in Python.

Comment: I like the phpmyadmin to get a sense of what is going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I think the solution is a lot easier, use "if not":

```
sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test1"
db1.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import MySQLdb


# Open database connection ( If database is not created don't give dbname)
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","yourusername","yourpassword","yourdbname" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# For creating create db
# Below line  is hide your warning 
cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 0; ")
# create db here....
cursor.execute("create database IF NOT EXISTS yourdbname")



# create table
cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 0; ")
cursor.execute("create table IF NOT EXISTS test (email varchar(70),pwd varchar(20));")
cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 1; ")

#insert data
cursor.execute("insert into test (email,pwd) values('test@gmail.com','test')")

# Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

#OUTPUT

mysql> select * from test;
+-----------------+--------+
| email           | pwd    |
+-----------------+--------+
| test@gmail.com  | test   |
+-----------------+--------+
```